# How can i design a table column as BIGINT in Sparx Systems Enterprise Architect?

Tags: enterprise-architect, bigint

I am using Sparx Systems Entrprise Architect 10.0. 
How can I tell EA to design a table column as Long or BIGINT respectively? There is only an option for INTEGER and NUMBER.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current project underlying database is not a specific one but a generic one. The datatypes are defined in a file which can be importet via Project-->Model Import/Export. This way the concrete underlying database can be canged more easily. this means that I have to define the missing datatype in this file...import the types and...et viola! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is to make sure you have set the correct database for your table element. Just double-click it and set the database in the Properties dialog. If you find that Long and BIGINT are still not available as types for your columns, then you can add them in the Database Datatypes dialog: go Settings > Database Datatypes and add them in there.

Comment: The datatype can be seen. Thy underlying DB is MySql.